# Add two tensor in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I got two tensors with shape `(X,y)` and `(y,)` respectively, is there any function in keras can add them togher? I only found the `K.bias_add` in [doc](https://keras.io/backend/) but it does not work. The error is:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor.
```

The types of my variables is:

```
>>x :<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> 
>>b :<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

Why this error occurs? How can I add two tensors together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compute the sum within a [Lambda](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer. For example:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from keras.models import Model

X = 3
y = 2

x = Input(shape=(X, y))
b = Input(shape=(y,))
out = Lambda(lambda a: a[0] + a[1])([x, b])
model = Model(inputs=[x, b], outputs=out)
```